# Width of depletion region in P-N junction

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Hello I wanted to ask how the width of the depletion region in reverse biased condition changes with the external  voltage source

Comment: This is given early on in every semiconductor device physics book that I own.

Comment: so how does it grow?

Comment: The implication is that some effort on your part is expected. If you are trying to learn about pn junctions, you must have found some material about them, and that material surely has an overview of the width of the junction vs bias conditions.

Comment: yes I have found some material but it doesn't explain if I have a reverse DV how the depletion region is increased

Comment: or it is decreased

Comment: electrons do move to the terminal of the n-type region and holes move to the terminal of the p-type region with a reverse bias voltage       if increase the reverse bias voltage until a certain level(breakdown voltage) how the bigger depletion region is created?

Comment: widening the depletion region? no more carriers can be attracted towards the terminals of the n-type and p-type regions  because all the carriers have already moved by a smaller external voltage source